# Xamarin IOS error: undefined symbol: _GPGUserDidSignOutNotification

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Did anyone had same problem and know how to fix it in Xamarin IOS?

> Error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _GPGUserDidSignOutNotification. This symbol was referenced by the managed member
>   Google.Play.GameServices.Manager.DidSignOutNotification. Please verify
>   that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native
>   libraries linked. (MT5214)

List of libraries:

- GooglePlus
- GoogleAnalytics
- monotouch
- MonoTouch.Dialog-1
- System
- System.Core
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq